# 2nd harddrive, /var/lib/mysql ownder is nvidia-persistenced when mounted, mysql when booted?

Tags: mysql, user-management

I have a second HDD that was my old OS. When I boot it the /var/lib/mysql folder is mysql:mysql but when I mount it (LVM) in my new OS it is nvidia-persistenced:vboxusers.

I want to do a cp -pr to the new system but cannot when the permissions are like this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User names are actaully just mappings to UIDs stored in `/etc/passwd`. Similarly group names are mapped to GIDs from `/etc/group`. The IDs are decided as and when they are required. 0 is always root but almost everything else is decided when the user and groups are created.

These *IDs are near-arbitrary integers that the system interprets as defined users and groups. The IDs are decided as and when they are required. 0 is always root but almost everything else is decided when the user and groups are created.

When a file is written to disk, it is these UID and GID values that are stored on disk, not the string representation. And that's what is happening here. Your user→UID and group→GID mappings in  on your secondary install don't line up with the UIDs from your first install. It's mapping file ownership to the wrong users.

If your old install is never going to be a factor in this, I would simply just remap the ownership to the mysql user:

```
sudo chown --recursive mysql: /var/lib/mysql
```

I've checked a real-world MySQL install and all the files in my `/var/lib/mysql` were owned by `mysql:mysql` so I think this should be accurate.

---

If the old install will be used again (eg a dual-boot-style arrangement) you'll need to be more creative. In those cases you might need to alter the mapping of UIDs and GIDs to users and groups so they're the same (and then fix the corresponding files from the new system). It would be fairly tedious.

Comment: Fantastic explanation, thanks for this, I was really baffled why vbox was getting into the mix too!

Comment: Btw, I am going to just change the ownership and if I need to boot back in then I can always change it back.

Comment: Also, I cannot edit the post since this is under 6 characters but can you change -r to -R or --recursive, -r doesn't work. Update: Well, I suppose --recursive is over 6 chars, I will edit.